# Python visual in Power BI - plot is too small

Tags: python, powerbi, python-visual

I have several Python visuals in Power BI.
The plots are always too small: the space is not utilized and therefore the plot is too small.

Tried to adjust the figure size, no effects

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 15))

Tried to reduce the padding, no effect

plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [15,5]
plt.plot(....plot your data....)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: PowerBI Python Visual]